# Product of Sum canonical transformation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This question is related to Logic Gates calculation.

Why is:

G = ( A + B + C * C' ) = ( A + B + C )*( A + B + C')

where + is OR, * is AND, ' is NOT.

Comment: the first bit is not wellformed do you mean (A + B + (C * C') == (A + B) or ((A + B + C) * C') == (A * C') + (B * C')?

Comment: Multiply-out the two parentheses on the right-hand-side and note that (X & X') is false. Also note that ((X & Y) + (X & Y')) is X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity denote $X = A + B$ and $Y = C'$

$X + C * Y = (X + C) * (X + Y)$      (distributive law)

Replace X by (A+B) and Y by C', you will have what you need to prove.

Comment: I've just looked it up on Wikipedia, this is Distribution of disjunction over conjunction. With the help of the Venn Diagram I understand it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) which fits for both sides of the equation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can see that in this Venn Diagram now.